# Run system command in android app

Tags: android

My device already rooted.
I write a function to run system command as below:

```
public void execCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc=runtime.exec("su");
    DataOutputStream opt = new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
    opt.writeBytes(command + "\n");
    opt.writeBytes("exit\n");
    opt.flush();

    try {
        if (proc.waitFor() != 0) {
            System.err.println("exit value = " + proc.exitValue());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

I try `execCommand("ifconfig")`, but it `get exit value = 1`.
How can I fix it?